# Printing DataGridView in PrintDocument

Tags: vb.net

I am a new to vb.net, I with my team are developing a system where we dominantly use DataGridView in viewing our records from SQL Server database.

Here's my problem, i have two DataGridViews where one extracts the ID and Student name while the other one extracts records(grades of the student) based on the other DataGridView row selected. I can already print the records but when i close the PrintDocument(without exiting the form) and choose another student and view it again in PrintDocument,

it gives me an error saying

`"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"`

and a follow-up problem occurs, when i have this code `"cell.RowIndex - 1"`, the first record in the DatagridView can't be printed in the PrintDocument and when i erase the "- 1" in the code, the header goes crazy, sometimes they go blank(w/ borders) and sometimes they really do not display, only the records are displayed.

this is where the error occurs:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1) 
    .Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString, .Font, 
     Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
```

This is my code:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    With DataGridView1
        Dim frmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        frmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        frmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

        Dim HeaderFont As Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 20)
        Dim reportFont As Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 14)
        Dim nrmlfnt As Font = New Drawing.Font("Calbiri", 10)
        Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        Dim blackpen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)

        e.Graphics.DrawString("First Fruits Christian Academy", HeaderFont, drawBrush, 250, 50)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Purok 17 Hindangon, Valencia City Bukidnon", reportFont, drawBrush, 245, 80)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Student Grade", reportFont, drawBrush, 370, 125)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Name: " & txtName.Text & "", nrmlfnt, drawBrush, 100, 180)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Gender: " & txtGender.Text & "", nrmlfnt, drawBrush, 600, 180)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grade & Section: " & cboYearLevel.Text & " - " & cboSection.Text & "", nrmlfnt, drawBrush, 100, 200)

        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top + 125
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width - 20, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                    If (newpage) Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
                    Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
                    End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to print things from a `DataGridView` is to make a collection of each row into a `List(Of String)` making use of `String.Format` to concatenate the values together. Use a class variable for where in the list you are at for the next pages to continue.

```
Private index As Integer
Private Sub Print(...) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
   Dim row As Integer = {some point you want to start at}
  'Paint a title - since this event fires for each page
  'continue loop or start loop
  For i As Integer = index To myList.Count - 1
   If Not row = e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 12 Then
    'remember where we are in the list
    index = i
    'paint your contents
   Else
    'start new page
    e.HasMorePages = True
    Exit Sub
   End If
  Next
  'reset the index for next print job
  If Not e.HasMorePages Then index = 0 
 End Sub

Dim myList As New List (Of String)
For Each row In dgv.Rows
  'add what data you want to print
Next
```

Comment: I'm sorry could you tell me what is "myList" in your code please...thanks

Comment: Like I said make a collection of what you want to print, that was my facticious version.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to remove the `Else` part from this code,

```
If (newpage) Then
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
Else
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
End If
```

And change it to,

```
If (newpage) Then
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
End If
' and at this point you should re-calculate your rectangle again
e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt)
```

The point is, **on each iteration, you have to print the row**, so if the newpage flag is true then it means you just need to print the header first before you print the line.

Comment: However OneFineDay's approach is more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

me and prove your code worked, now the problem is that servers provide last row of data. 
I made changes to make it work are:

```
Dim NewPage As Boolean 
  NewPage = True 

  If (NewPage) = True Then 
    e.Graphics.DrawString (FDesempeño.DataGridView1.Columns (cell.ColumnIndex) .HeaderText, .font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt) 
 
else 
  e.Graphics.DrawString (FDesempeño.DataGridView1.Rows (cell.RowIndex - 1) .Cells (cell.ColumnIndex) .FormattedValue.ToString, .font, Brushes.Black, rc, frmt) 
End If
```

I hope you found served, by the way I am newbie like you. if you can correct the error if I agradesericia you can contact us by email, my email is pablo_buy@hotmail.com